# Arquivo sql ou direto no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hoje uma dúvida me surgiu, estava criando uma tabela no banco de dados e me deparei se devo fazer isso manualmente, diretamente no banco de dados ou criar essa tabela através de queries, criando uma página `.sql`. O que seria melhor e mais seguro?

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer o DER, no MySQL Workbench e mandar gerar o script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponho que quando diz manualmente, se refere à linha de comando.

Isso se resume apenas à forma que você insere a informação, não há melhor ou pior, faça o que lhe convir melhor (normalmente cl). Sobre segurança, deve-se atentar que para realizar qualquer script sobre a sua base de dados, você precisa estar autenticado.

Comment: Manualmente que me refiro seria indo no banco de dados e criando a tabela diretamente nele. Mas entendi, é mais questão de preferência mesmo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não há uma forma padrão de criar tabelas ou dados no banco, mas para facilitar e agilizar seu trabalho use um gerenciador de bancos de dados, vai da sua preferência.